# duplicate key error primary key django and mongo (djongo)

Tags: django, mongodb, django-models, djongo

i have some data in my model Paper with id primary key
from id = 1 - 30

id field created by django

but now when i create new object it want to created with id = 1
then raise a duplicate error

i dont have any idea can anybody help me ?

Comment: That's very simple. put your own logic to `valiadate` the `object_id`. if you didn't found any help then we're here to help you.

Comment: What do you want to do with old object with same id, id is unique